# how to Populate list view with list of strings from web service (not from array)?

Tags: java, android, json

I have to populate my list view with two strings from a web service. I have already written the code to populate my list view with a single string from the webservice but I don't know how to populate it with two strings.

here is my code so far, help me out guys.

```
try {
  JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(s);
  for (int i=0; i<ar.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = ar.getJSONObject(i);
    Flowers  flowers = new Flowers();
    flowers.setName(jsonobject.getString("NAME"));
    flowersList.add(flowers);
  }
}
```

Comment: If i got you correct, you should use custom adapter with your list view

Comment: How to use it bro...am newbie

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials out there on how to use custom list view, alternative way (easy way) would be to combine the 2 strings since you were able to populate the first one just go and concat the 2 strings and then you should have them

Comment: @MilkaMozhi check this https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about adding a second property to this Flowers element and displaying both of these two properties in your list, i suggest you to overwrite the ToString() method in the Flowers class.

If you are working with Android Studio you can just type ToString in the Flowers class and it will probably suggest you to overwrite it.
Another option is to press ALT+Insert->ToString(if i recall correctly).

The ToString class basically creates a String that represents the Entity, so if you would type `return "Name: " + name + " Color: " + color` it would display something like this:

> Name: Rose Color: Red

Comment: @MilkaMozhi check this https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: class Flowers  {

    public String getName() {

        return NAME;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.NAME = name;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flowers{" +
                "NAME='" + NAME + "PERCENTAGE" +
                PERCENTAGE;
    }

    private String NAME;

}

Comment: it doesn't look like you have a PERCENTAGE attribute in your class, create it the same way you did with the NAME attribute